# Stop transmitting audio when app is in background in android webRTC/AppRTC

Tags: android, webrtc, audiotrack, apprtc, apprtcdemo

I am working on webRTC on the android platform. I run the appRTC code(https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo). Now I joined the call from the android mobile and one from the web(https://appr.tc/). it is working fine. Now Android mobile goes in background and I observed after sometime voice is not transmitting from android to web. but if the app comes in the foreground then it works. but again app goes in background, after sometime audio/voice transmitting is not happening.

Comment: Shashank if you tried any code then please share it, or you can use foreground service when your app goes background start service and start transmitting the data with service.